# A firefox plugin for driving UI of web apps

Tags: web-applications, user-interface, firefox-addon, automated-tests

Does anyone know of a firefox plugin that can be used to drive the UI of a Web app?

Answer (score 0):

SeleniumHQ http://seleniumhq.org/. It works also in many other browsers.